# Prove a function is not in a Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform, fractional-sobolev-spaces

A way to check that a $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ function is in $H^{3/2}(\mathbb{R})$, is to check that $(1+|\xi|^2)^{3/4}{\mathscr{F}}(f)$ is in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

I am interested on problems on the half-line. To check that a function in $L^2([0,\infty))$ is in  $H^{3/2}([0,\infty))$ if there is an extension of that function that is in $H^{3/2}(\mathbb{R})$. What about proving that something is not in $H^{3/2}([0,\infty))$? Is there a criterion, or a way to determine if a given function is not in  $H^{3/2}([0,\infty))$ other then, for each case, proving there is no extension.

I am using $k=3/2$, $p=2$, and the half-line because that is what I am interested in. But my question can be applied to $H^{k,p}(I)$ for other values of $k$ and p, and other open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$. This question is related to my other question,  [Sobolev space on the half-line](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3784620/80734).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One criteria follows from the following.

**Theorem:** If for $u \in H^k([0,\infty))$ with $k \leq 2,$ if we define
$$ Eu(x) = \begin{cases}
    u(x) & \text{ if } x \geq 0, \\
    u(-x)+3u(-x/3)-3u(-2x/3) & \text{ if } x < 0,
  \end{cases}$$
then $Eu \in H^k(\Bbb R),$ with comparable norms.

It may be possible to use a simpler extension here, but I would need to check the details. This can be shown by showing these fractional spaces can be equivalently defined using the Gagliardo seminorm, and establishing a suitable extension theorem. The details are essentially covered in [the following reference](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4345):

> Nezza, Palatucci, Valdinoci. *Hitchhiker's guide to the fractional Sobolev spaces.* arXiv:1104.4345v3  [math.FA]

This gives an explicit means to check if an element lies in $H^k([0,\infty));$ you compute its extension, and check if that lies in $H^k(\Bbb R).$ If $Eu \not\in H^k(\Bbb R),$ then you can conclude that $u \in H^k([0,\infty)).$

*Note*: If you are trying to show explicit functions don't lie in this Sobolev space, there are many necessary conditions for $u \in H^k([0,\infty))$ that might be easier to verify; local $H^k$ regularity ($\eta u \in H^k(\Bbb R)$ for all $\eta \in C^{\infty}_c((0,\infty))$), whether $u$ has the correct Hölder regularity, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a way to get that theorem from a result in the paper? I see Lemma 5.2. If I apply Lemma 5.2 to a function in $H^{3/2}([0,\infty))$ then, for the function, it would mans that the extension reads $Eu(x)=u(x), x>0, -u(-x) x<0$. Where does your result come from?

Comment: @Stephane The result I assert doesn't quite follow from the paper, which only considers the case when $k \in (0,1).$ However you can obtain analogues of Proposition 3.4 and Lemma 5.2 when $k = 3/2$ by similar arguments, though I'm not aware of references that prove this in detail (and in the one-dimensional case I suspect there are easier ways to show this). In this case you need a higher order extension however, and the one I provided has the property that if $u \in C^2([0,\infty))$ then $Eu \in C^2(\Bbb R).$

Comment: I thought the restriction $k \in (0,1)$ is done WLOG for the following reason. To check that $f$ is in $H^{n+k}$ is equivalent to checking if $f^{(n)}$ is in $H^{k}$. So, if I use Lemma 5.2 in the paper for $3/2$ and want to check if $u$ is in $H^{3/2}([0,\infty))$,  I would need to check if $Eu'(x)=u'(x),\;\;x>0,\;\;u'(-x),\;x<0$ is in $H^{1/2}$, which is equivalent to check if $Eu(x)=u(x),\;\;x>0,\;\;-u(-x),\;x<0$ is in $H^{3/2}$. Does that make sense or am I saying something wrong? Thank you again.

Comment: @Stephane That indeed works provided you can separately show that $u \in H^1([0,\infty)),$ which I suppose is usually easier to verify in practice.

Comment: @ ktoi That's great. That response of yours and the following discussion was really helpful. Thank you.